# is there a simple front for sql server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

i am in a multi-user environment

i am using access as a front end connecting to sql server database. i am allowing users to edit only one table in sql server.

i dont want to continue using access to edit a sql-server table.

can someone recommend another tool to do this?

Comment: Not sure how much simpler it can get. Is there another problem you aren't mentioning?

Comment: @jeff o, problem is that we have to pay $150 for every access license

Comment: @jeff o, plus access is not that stable, as i am sure you are aware

Comment: Access 2007 runtime is free: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=d9ae78d9-9dc6-4b38-9fa6-2c745a175aed&displaylang=en

Comment: @Jenny and just how is Access not stable?

Comment: @remou what is the diff between runtime and regular thing? what can i do with the runtime?

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136539.aspx

Comment: Access is perfectly stable, just as a power saw is perfectly safe in the hands of someone who knows how to use it.

Comment: @david i really like ur analogy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Access 2007 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=D9AE78D9-9DC6-4B38-9FA6-2C745A175AED) and the [Access 2010 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=57A350CD-5250-4DF6-BFD1-6CED700A6715) is free for the download from Microsofts website.   Of course you'd want to purchase Access licenses for power users who want to create their own queries usually for export to Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Either Access or Excel are almost certainly the simplest solutions available that meet your requirements, when you consider both the simplicity of the user interface itself and the simplicity of implementing, deploying, and maintaining the solution for the users. Creating even a simple web page isn't nearly so simple – you'll need to setup a web server, configure user security, develop the web page, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use SSMS -- Sql Server Management Studio.

**Update**

Found a near duplicate @SU: [Less daunting front end for SQL Server](https://superuser.com/questions/18527/less-daunting-front-end-for-sql-server)

**Update 2**

Try to use [Microsoft ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata). And [a tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpiU5Y8luOQ), of course.

Comment: @denis no  - i need something simple which people who do not know how to  use a computer can use

Comment: @jenny Create a simple web page with a datagrid on it with insert, update and delete functionality on a particular table.

Comment: @jenny - It's probably a **TERRIBLE** idea to give people who "do not how to use a computer" direct access to SQL!  There's a reason home electronics have panels that say "No user servicable parts" - people who aren't qualified probably shouldn't monkey around with the mechanics of it.

Comment: @denis great idea - can you please direct me on how to do this

Comment: @jenny Something like this perhaps? http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2009/11/jqgrid-and-aspnet-mvc-crud.html

Answer (score 1):

If you pull down a copy of visual studio express you could build a single screen application that allows editing a table with just drag and drop from the server explorer.  No coding needed unless you're looking to add some more advanced logic.

Alternatively you could just use Access to also build a one screen front end - with that as the start up form to your Access DB your users wouldn't even know they're in Access.

Edit:

1. Assuming you're in a windows domain - put all your users in to a security group and then grant this group access to the SQL Server.  Only grant the group permissions on the specific objects that they need to edit.
2. Create a blank Access DB.
3. Link your SQL Server table in to the Access DB - e.g. in 2007 the option is in the External Data ribbon > more... > ODBC database.
4. Once you have the table linked create a form to edit the data by doing Create > more > Form Wizard.

This allows you to pick the exact columns you want them to edit, pick a layout etc.

From here the options are really only limited by how much effort you want to put in but it's a good start in contrast to direct table access.

Comment: this is great advice, how do i do this with access

Comment: @jenny - don't know how much you know about SQL & Access but the above should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to give CRUD access to a table in a SQL Server database.

Suggest making a simple page - use ASP.NET Dynamic Data. Watch this [video to get started with ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/aspnet-in-net-35-sp1/videos/getting-started-with-dynamic-data).

Failing that, provision the user with Microsoft Access.

- setup a new user in SQL Server, and give it permissions on that table only.
- setup Access to read, update, create and delete that table. Use the credentials of the user in the bullet above. This will ensure they can't mess anything else up.
- Only bring that table into the user's view.

Comment: camp this is a great idea, how do i Only bring that table into the user's view.

Comment: Does the term CRUD mean Create, Read, Update and Delete?   I assume it does.

Comment: I have never quite understood why anyone uses the term. Isn't very database application on the planet a CRUD app?

Comment: @Tony @David: sure, all database apps are crud apps. I guess I'm missing your point. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

Comment: What does the ugly acronym add to the discussion?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's still in Beta but you might want to also take a look at [WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix).